# Stream different videos and sounds to Bluetooth headphones & loudspeakers

Tags: audio, sound-volume, soundflower

I have Bluetooth headphones & loudspeakers.

I want to stream sound from iTunes to Bluetooth headphones and a YouTube video to the loudspeakers.

I know that OS X allows to stream one source to both devices, but I want to stream each stream to different devices.

I know that in Windows it's possible via Realtek utility, but how about OS X?

Answer (score 1):

OS X itself supports each app using a different device, as long as that app support select a device instead of using the default one.
Unfortunately neither iTunes or Safari supports alternative device unless that's an AirPlay device.

You have still two options here:

1. get an AirPlay enabled device, so you may choose device in iTunes or Youtube Player (which is powered by HTML 5 not Flash)
2. get another music app other than iTunes, I'd recommend Vox for Mac[1] which supports play iTunes Library and a lot more, you may choose device in the app.

UPDATE 2016/02/20
AirFoil 5 for Mac[2] now supports set different audio source for different apps.

[1] http://coppertino.com/vox/mac
[2] https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/

Comment: yes, i understand what you tallking about. i have kodi installed with airplay enabled on Mac and when i start video on youtube says that airplay device have and try to detecting.